# MVC5 Populate dropdownlist from a different table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

My controller is as follows

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.ClubList = GetClubs();

        return View();
    }

    public static List<SelectListItem> GetClubs()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> ls = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var club = new ClubsService().RecordView().ToList();
        foreach (var item in club)
        {
            ls.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.clubID.Trim(), Value = item.clubID.Trim() });
        }

        return ls;
    }
```

And my View is as follows

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.clubID, ViewBag.ClubList, new { @style = "width:400px; text-align: left", @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })
```

This is generating an error

> ('HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
>   'DropDownListFor' and the best extension method overload
>   'SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor(HtmlHelper, Expression>,
>   IEnumerable, object)' has some invalid arguments.

ClubID comes from the Clubs table where the model I am populating comes from the products table.

Can someone send me in the right direction. Bit new to MVC.

Thanks.

Comment: `ViewBag` is dynamic - you need to cast it - `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.clubID, (IEnumareble<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ClubList, new { ... })` (just another reason why you should always use a view model and that view model would contain a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

Comment: And please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use another way to prevent loop and get expected result

```
var club = new ClubsService().RecordView().ToList();
ViewBag.ClubList = new SelectList(club, "clubID", "clubID");
```

first `clubID` defines the value and second `clubID` defines the text, i used both `clubID`
Because in your example you used `item.clubID`
and in view

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.clubID, (SelectList)ViewBag.ClubList,"-- Select Clubs --", new { @style = "width:400px; text-align: left", @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the ViewBag, why not create a ViewModel for your view add a property to your ViewModel that is a selectList

```
public string ClubID {get; set;}
public SelectList ClubList { get; set; }
```

You can add all the fields your view is going to use in this model. Make sure you initialize the SelectList in the ViewModel constructor

```
ClubList = new SelectList();
```

Then inside your controller, create an instance of the view model, get the data and pass it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.ClubList = GetClubs();

    return View(model);
}

public static SelectList GetClubs()
{

    var club = new ClubsService().RecordView().ToList();
    var ls = new SelectList(club, "clubID", "clubID");
    return ls;
}
```

And in you view, at the top, you can say:

```
@model namespace.Where.ViewModel
```

then you can say:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.clubID, Model.ClubList, "Please Select...", new { @style = "width:400px; text-align: left", @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your view file doesn't know about `public static List<SelectListItem> GetClubs()`. Add your namespace to the web.config file in the root of your view folders:

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers"/>
        <!--ADD YOUR NAMESPACE HERE-->
        <add namespace="MyCustomHelpers"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: It doesn't need to - the value is assigned to a `ViewBag` property in the controller.